# Share session values in subdomains Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project in which i want to share the session values among subdomains. for example i set the session values in **abc.com** and now i want to access those values in following subdomains **first.abc.com** and **second.abc.com**. These domains are handled using same code on a server. I have tried following method but it does not work for me.

In app/config/session.php i changed the domain value to following.

```
'domain' => '.abc.com'
```

Then cleared all the browser cookies and the session from laravel storage directory but it does not work.

Please suggest something where i am doing mistake.

Comment: possible duplicate.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338518/persisting-sessions-across-subdomains-in-laravel-5

Comment: @zaheerAttar i already tried the method mentioned there but it is not working.

Comment: how about this one.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39739363/5350773

Comment: @zaheerAttar no it is not the problem.

Comment: have you tried database solution written here..?https://stackoverflow.com/a/39741256/5350773

Comment: yes it did not worked.