# Automatic Log In/Authentication Laravel from Other Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have two Laravel applications that use the same database and, therefore, have the same users and passwords.

Let's say the applications are called A and B.

If a user logs into A, what can I do so that they're automatically logged into B? So if they log into A, then when they go to B, they will not have to type in their login information again.

Both applications are on the same domain, but B is a subdomain and is not part of the same project as A.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: couldn't you set a token in the backend, and just have the request include that token and log them in through `Auth::login($user);`   or something similar?

Comment: I suppose I could do that. How would application B know to check for that when the user goes there from A?

Comment: maybe modify the Auth middleware to look for it?  or perhaps in the constructor for the controller(s) you just include the `Request $request` and see if it contains the token.

Comment: I'll try that, and I'll report back the result.

Comment: I once did this in php by changing the session cookies path to `*.mydomain.foo`. Perhaps something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488477/authuser-doesnt-travel-across-subdomains-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 1):

When you say `Both applications are on the same domain, but B is a subdomain and is not part of the same project as A.` can i safely assume that they are two separate installations of Laravel, but they share the same database? I that's the case, you could try this:

- Switch the session driver to database in your `.env` file to "database", for reference you should look at the comments in `config/session.php`, near the `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),` option. Be sure to manage the tables accordingly (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#driver-prerequisites)
- In your `.env` file, specify this row: `SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.ext` (notice the dot near the equal sign).

Alternatively, if even the databases are separate you could try the same config as above using the `cookie` driver instead fo the database. let me know if this helped.

**edit:** more a suggestion than an answer, laravel is capable of handling multiple websites/domains natively (example: `Route::domain('sub.domain.ext')`. Pratically speaking, you organize the routes this way in `routes/web.php`. With a wise database management (and queries) you can easily mantain 2 separate websites within 1 Laravel application. This assuming you have control over your webserver, of course. If that's the case, i would suggest a refractoring. It's really worth the effort.