# Laravel subdomain: single auth across all subs not working?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session, subdomain

I'm building a site with a dynamic subdomain system eg (name.domain.com). I'm using Ubuntu with laravel's serve command.

ive set it all up in my routes as so:

```
Route::domain('{x}.localhost')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/url/',  'SomeController@someAction')->middleware('can:xyz,x')->name('someName');
});
```

Now, everything works great, apart from the fact Auth is subdomain locked

eg(xyz.localhost:8000/ , localhost:8000/) require separate logins.

after a bit of googling I read, I can overwrite this in the config/session.php file under 'domain'. So in my .env file I set up a new var for SESSION_DOMAIN and point it to ".localhost" or ".localhost:800" or just for testing I get the same with the IP 127.0.0.1 / :8000 as suggested however when I try to login my session is not valid right after login eg( i log in and get redirected to the correct route but my auth catches that I'm not logged in)

session config

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

my .env

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
```

It seems like no cookies are being set for some reason?

Should probably note this is happening using both files and the database for sessions, I've also cleared out my cache and session storage each time along with cookies, etc.

-- I've tried everything I can think of over the last few days to solve this with no luck. Even on a fresh install of laravel the same issue is there.

I can log in with FF on the main URL, but on the sub URL I'm not logged in and I get a 419 if I try.

Any suggestions? Kind regards, Matt

-Edit

To reproduce on a new install of laravel, first, install the auth package:

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue --auth
npm run dev
```

Next, edit your .env file with your Mysql database info and add this line to the file:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
```

Last of all add this to your web.php routes file.

```
Route::domain('{foobar}.localhost')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/test/',  'HomeController@index');
});
```

(i like to create an account here in the command line)
Then push the default migrations and run the server and test by logging in on the home page and then any subdomain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auth::user() doesn't travel across subdomains? - Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488477/authuser-doesnt-travel-across-subdomains-laravel-5-2)

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34488988/7354094

Comment: Unfortuantlyi have tried that, you can set the Domain value in the .env under ```SESSION_DOMAIN``` When this is set Auth breaks and doesn't set session cookies for some reason.

Here is the current Session config file regarding sessions.

``` 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null), ```

Answer (score 4):

Well its because of the localhost domain, instead use virtual domain like something.test and then set SESSION_DOMAIN=.something.test and clear out cache. localhost and 127.0.0.1 are not same origin so cannot set session.

Comment: Hi TEFO, thanks for the reply.
Could you elaborate a little more, please? I'm not sure I'm following you. 
When I'm testing I'm only using localhost, 127.0.0.1 was just a try to see if it would work. Ive tried to set up a host in my hosts file and point it to 127.0.0.1:8000 but i get the same issue.
Kind regards.

Comment: well for setting sessions(cookies) you need exact origin of url which means you dont access cookies that set on localhost:8000 in 127.0.0.1:8000 and that true with localhost and localhost:8000. for example check localhost on your machine its probably different project.

Comment: Hi TEFO, I'm sorry, again I'm not sure if I'm just wildly not following you or you have misunderstood my question. I apologize if it's myself being silly.

Im only using one domain for the site, im not trying to access the site through different top-level domains like localhost:8000 and 127.0.01:8000 rather im trying to just access the site through dynamic subdomains like localhost:8000, test.localhost:8000, foobar.localhost:8000. I'll edit my original post for steps to reproduce.

Comment: @Makka In your host file, add `127.0.0.1 something.test` and `127.0.0.1 foo.something.test` don't specify the port. Then set `SESSION_DOMAIN=.something.test` as @TEFO said, the session will be persisted on both `http://something.test:8000` and `http://foo.something.test:8000`

Answer (score 1):

For your information, There is a cookies and session storage to persist the session and laravel also supports persisting the session in the database. session cookies have the domain to which it is accessible, so you need to configure the `session.php` file to adopt subdomains. single Auth is not working across all your subdomains because you haven't configured it well. Here is how you can do it.

You'll need to update the session configuration to persist the session in domain-wide including subdomains. Follow the steps given below.

1. Setup the virtual host first to use in the application. Then after you can use the virtual host for subdomains as well. For now you are using the `localhost` which is not the domain at all. It's a loopback address in TCP/IP model. See [rfc2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) definition.
2. Go to **`config/session.php`** and update the **`domain`** with prefix **`.`** as **`config => '.your-domain.com'`**.
3. Then clear your application cache, Open the Chrome DevTool and Go to **Application > Application > Clear Storage**. You'll need to clear out the previous **cookies** also.
4. run artisan command **`php artisan config:cache`** or **`php artisan config:clear`** to drop previously cached laravel application configs.

If you are using **database** as the session driver, You need to create a session table for that. run command **`php artisan session:table`** to generate the session table migration and then migrate it using **`php artisan migrate`**. Then perform the four steps given above. You can refer to my similar answer which is logically same with your concern [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338518/persisting-sessions-across-subdomains-in-laravel-5/59213411#59213411)