# Nuxt with laravel sanctum recieve "Unauthenticated" message

Tags: php, laravel, api, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use Laravel sanctum with NuxtJS. The problem is I'm able to pass the get csrf and login but when i try to access the api/user, I get "Unauthorized" message. They say i should set SESSION_DRIVER to cookie but it's still the same. I'm using xampp so I'm running the laravel on **localhost:8000** and nuxtjs on **localhost:3000**. Thanks in advance.

[image: Unauthenticated]

***Laravel API***

**.env**

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost
```

**config/cors**

```
'paths' => [
    'api/*',
    '/login',
    '/logout',
    '/sanctum/csrf-cookie'
],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

**api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
   return $request->user();
});
```

**NUXT JS**

**nuxt.config.js**

```
axios: {
     baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/",
     credentials: true
},
auth: {
   redirect: {
       login: '/login',
       logout: '/',
       callback: '/login',
       home: '/'
   },
   strategies: {
          local: {
             endpoints: {
                login: { url: '/login', method: 'post', propertyName: false },
                user: { url: '/api/user', method: 'get', propertyName: false }
             },
             tokenRequired: false,
             tokenType: false
          }
   },
   localStorage: false
},
```

**Login.vue**

```
export default {
data(){
    return{
        email:'',
        password:''
    }
},
components: {

},
methods:{
    login(){
        this.$axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie', {
            headers: {
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            withCredentials: true,
        })
        .then( function(){
            this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
                data: {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                },
            });
        }.bind(this))
    }
},
mounted(){  
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/issues/41

Comment: In order for this to work properly the SPA would need to send back the value of the XSRF-TOKEN cookie under the request header X-XSRF-TOKEN, which currently does not seem to be documented here, but this is how Laravel resolves encrypted CSRF cookies.

Comment: Reading the token from the cookie header like the middleware above does will not protect against CSRF since that cookie is sent along with the request regardless of where it came from, defeating the purpose of CSRF protection entirely.

Comment: @AjayKadoula yeah i've read that before. But i think I've configured axios properly to send the request with the csrf token by setting credentials: true in nuxt.config.js .. so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: this are not same origins means this two domain for front and back have different ports. this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62417776/7908390

Answer (score 2):

in nuxt.config.js,
check local server port like this :

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      'laravelSanctum': {
       provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
       url: 'http://localhost:8000'
       },
    },
  },

  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
    credentials: true
  },
```

if true:

in .env file check this :

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
```

then check your laravel kernel.php file and add this class if dosnt exist:

```
'api' => [
        EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your config! For my issue, it was the `.env` value for `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` not having the port number. This is correct: `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000`